# Comparison between the performance parameters of Tristate buffer and Schmitt Trigger

Tags: buffer, schmitt-trigger, tri-state, performance

I want to know the comparison between the performance parameters of Tristate buffer and Schmitt Trigger. By performance parameters, I mean things like propagation delay,power consumption etc.

Thank you

**Edit**

I want to know, for example, if I use tri-state buffer as a repeater in a simple circuit, will it make propagation delay less than that if I use schmitt trigger as a repeater in that same circuit ? If so then why ?

Comment: Oranges are orange, apples come in many colours. A Schmitt Trigger is a different beast from a tri-state buffer. The parameters you mention are specific to a particular device and listed in their spec sheets. If you want to compare one device against another, compare the spec sheets.

Comment: It is possible to have a tri-state buffer with schmitt trigger input characteristics.  The details you want will vary widely between different logic families, but will be covered in the appropriate data sheets..

Comment: Yes, I know Schmitt trigger is different thing from tri-state buffer. I want to know, for example, if I use tri-state buffer as a repeater in a simple circuit, will it make propagation delay less than that if I use schmitt trigger as a repeater in that same circuit ? If so then why ?

Answer (score 0):

If strongly driven with fast edges, your choice of delay comes down to technology and # internal inverters.

Again, you want small geometry CMOS, with just one or 2 stages on Inverters.
Examine the delays of non-inverting TriStage buffers; the TriState circuit is merely an Inverter with extra FETS, to enable or disable; to maintain data polarity, at least one more inverter is needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffl7bS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>